# TAB completion not working in ubuntu hardy heron

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

I have recently installed ubuntu hardy and found that shell command completion with TAB doesn't work, the package 'bash-completion' is installed in my system. I guess it is related to dash being the default shell? Is there a way to use tab completion in dash? If there isn't a way then how can i change my default shell to bash?

Comment: Thus the question really isn't "Tab doesn't work", it's, "Running the wrong shell".  Note that you can run bash from dash with "/bin/bash" and immediately see if the tab key works there. "exit" to get back to dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash shouldn't be the default user shell. That would make life much less convenient, because bash is way more usable in interactive sessions. You can check what shell you're actually running with `echo $SHELL`.

Have a look at `/etc/bash.bashrc` around line 32. Uncomment the enabling configuration.

Comment: It's also enabled (or can be) on a per-user basis in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: If he added his account (i.e. not the first account made), using adduser instead of useradd, I believe it defaults to sh.

Comment: Thanks Novelocrat, uncommenting at /etc/bash/bash.rc solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I believe sh is actually symlinked to /bin/dash in Ubuntu.  There is no tab completion support with this shell.  To set your shell to bash use the following command:

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash username
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle, for your response. But changing the shell didn't solve it, i had to edit /etc/bash/bash.rc

Comment: Very strange, I've never had to do that with any Ubuntu version, but I do see the code in bash.bashrc.

Comment: Actually, to change your shell, use `chsh` command, not `sudo ...`

Answer (score 0):

/bin/sh is symlinked to /bin/dash
To change it, do:
sudo rm /bin/sh
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

Comment: I don't think "correct it" is the right phrase. "Change it" would be better. The ubuntu folks wrote up something explaining why they changed the symlink for sh to point to dash instead of bash https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh . It looks like bash is better for interactive site and dash is faster for running shell scripts.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, changed. +1